# Powershell Error during Active Directory Application MainLogo picture upload

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I can successfully create a new Azure Active Directory Application in powershell using the cmdlet **New-AzureADApplication**, however I am unable to add the application logo using powershell for my application. 
Below is the code and the error:

```
Set-AzureADApplication -MainLogo (Get-Content "C:\Users\Test\Logo.png" -encoding BYTE)
```

**Error:**

> Set-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing SetApplication 
>   StatusCode: BadRequest
>   ErrorCode: Request_BadRequest
>   Message: **A stream property 'mainLogo' has a value in the payload. In OData, stream property must not have a value, it must only use property annotations.**
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Set-AzureADApplication -MainLogo (Get-Content
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AzureADApplication], ApiException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.SetApplication

The documentation provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azuread/v2/set-azureadapplication) only mentions the usage as
*Set-AzureADApplication [-MainLogo ]* however I could not find any examples on using this parameter with Set or New-AzureADApplication cmdlet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the command as below, and get the same error message. Based on the results, I recommend to submit a support request [here](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview).

```
[Byte[]]$logo=Get-Content "C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\test.png" -encoding BYTE
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId "46dcfdd9-e0c4-4623-8139-73936a716034" -MainLogo $logo
```

However, as an alternative, you still can upload the logo on Azure portal. Just logging in to the Azure portal, you can choose the **Azure Active Directory** extension from the left panel, and find the specific application from the **Enterprise Applications**. From the **Properties**, you can upload the logo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

-MainLogo accepts byte type only. It won't accept any file like that.

> [-MainLogo ]

You can use this for conversion:

```
Param([String]$path)
[convert]::ToBase64String((get-content $path -encoding byte))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Ranadip, can you provide more information on how you use the converted base64 string with the set-AzureADApplication cmdlet and -mainLogo parameter? Thanks!